# How epoll use in python?

Tags: python, epoll

How epoll use in python?
i wonder   thousands of connections including 'tcp' or "http", when "tcp" i only check the connectivity.when http i send http if possible. how epoll write in python

That is my status, i want to know how to use epoll in python
please show some code for me. thanks

Comment: You are new and english is obviously your second language but please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before editing or posting another question. There is a right way and wrong way to post a question on here an as of now, your question falls in the wrong category. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Access to epoll is available in [the `select` library as part of the standard Python libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use a wrapper like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).  Blurb from website:

> Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library, originally developed at FriendFeed. By using non-blocking network I/O, Tornado can scale to tens of thousands of open connections, making it ideal for long polling, WebSockets, and other applications that require a long-lived connection to each user.